# A spherical version of the generalized half-angle formulas

Tags: euclidean-geometry, spherical-geometry

The following is a generalization of the half-angle formulas presented at [Nabla - Applications of Trigonometry](http://www.nabla.hr/GE-AppTrigonomB1.htm).

**Generalization**. Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ be the sides of a general convex quadrilateral, $s$ is the semiperimeter, and  $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are opposite angles, then
$$ad\sin^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}+bc\cos^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}=(s-a)(s-d)\qquad\qquad bc\sin^2{\frac{\gamma}{2}}+ad\cos^2{\frac{\alpha}{2}}=(s-b)(s-c).\tag{1}$$
I am interested in the following:
**a)** If possible, a spherical generalization of $(1)$.
**b)** If **a)** is answered in the affirmative, what [classical metric relations of spherical trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Half-angle_and_half-side_formulae) would follows from **a)** (or a particular case of a)?

This question is related to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456365/the-theoretical-importance-of-the-half-angle-formulas).

Crossposted at [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474630/a-spherical-version-of-the-generalized-half-angle-formulas)